# How to force Firebase Database value/child listener to be called on a non-main thread?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Each time we ask Firebase to notify us of value or child changes, the callback is always called on the main thread.

If we listen for child changes on a subtree that has thousands of children, the main thread will be blocked for quite a while.

And sometimes we don't need our listeners to be called on the main thread, for example when we want to custom-sort the data first before exposing it to the UI.

Is there a way to force Firebase SDK to call our event listeners on a specific thread?

Comment: Firebase ensures that the network handling and decoding of the JSON all happen off the main thread already. It only then surfaces the call to your callback on the main thread, so that you can update the UI. If there is significant time being spent in your callback, you'll have to use the regular [Android background task mechanisms](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to fix that. But without seeing your code, we have no way of helping you determine the correct fix.